# Deploying create-react-app express api to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, create-react-app

I have an app that uses a React/Redux client (generated by create-react-app) and it communicates with a Node/Express api. When I run this during development, it works perfectly.

I just deployed to Heroku for the first time however, and only the client side of my app is working. I get error messages in the console that the api routes return a 404.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I think it must be something simple like adding a script to package.json.

**UPDATE: SOLVED:** The issue was a freaking Procfile. Make sure to include a `Procfile` and write `web: node server` inside.